# Pascal passing a listview from mainform to a nonmodal form

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I have a listview in my mainform that I want another nonmodal form to be able to add things to. 
How would I pass the listview to the nonmodal form? 
The form I want to be able to modify it is shown by the MainForm on a button click, just with Form.Show.

I should also clarify that I want the form to not use the mainform to avoid circular reference.

Comment: ** I should also clarify that I want the form to not use the mainform to avoid circular reference.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** The question was originally tagged Delphi. I don't know FPC/Lazarus so some of the details may not be accurate below but the concepts are still valid.

---

I'm guessing that you have a global variable representing the main form, named `MainForm` for the sake of argument. The quickest and simplest approach is simply to use `MainForm.ListView` to let your other form refer to the main form's list view.

I'm not terribly keen on this approach since it means that the other form takes a dependency on the implementation of the main form.

---

As an alternative, you can pass a reference to the list view to the other form. For example you could add a `SetListView` procedure to your other form:

```
type
  TMyOtherForm = class(TForm)
  private
    FListView: TListView;
  public
    procedure SetListView(Value: TListView);
  end;
.....
procedure TMyOtherForm.SetListView(Value: TListView);
begin
  FListView := Value;
end;
```

Then in the main form, probably in the `OnCreate` event handler for the main form, you can call this method:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyOtherForm.SetListView(ListView);
end;
```

This isn't really all that much better than the first suggestion. The other form still takes a dependency on the implementation of the main form, albeit an arguably less significant dependency.

---

If you want to keep the two forms even less coupled then the main form could expose a method that accepts additions to the list:

```
procedure TMainForm.AddToList(const Name: sting; const Time: TDateTime);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := Name;
  Item.SubItems.Add(DateTimeToStr(Time));
end;
```

The in your other forms unit you add the main form unit to the uses clause in the implementation section. That allows you access to the `MainForm` global variable and you can call

```
MainForm.AddToList(Name, Time);
```

This approach is the best in my view because it allows the main form to keep its list implementation private to itself.

---

You state in a comment that you want to avoid any circular references due to `uses` clauses. That's easy to arrange since none of the above require modifications to the `uses` clause from the interface section from the two units in question.

Comment: Your 3rd approach seems like what I would want to do. Where exactly would you declare this procedure? It's the mainform's public declarations? and in the otherform would you just do TMainForm.AddToList() without it needing to use TMainform?

Comment: Yes it has to be a public in TMainForm. You add your main form unit to the implementation section uses clause in your other unit. Then you do `MainForm.AddToList`. Don't try `TMainForm.AddToList`. That won't work.

Comment: Apparently I actually do not have a global variable for mainform. Where would I declare my the mainform to be global?

Comment: @wentime That's unusual. A normal Delphi app adds that for you by default. The .dpr usually creates the main form and assigns to a global variable that is declared in the interface section of your main form's unit. You have to call `Application.CreateForm` to do that somewhere? Where do you do that and what do you do with the reference that you pass to `Application.CreateForm`?

Comment: I am using Lazarus and I don't see any call to CreateForm anywhere in the code for unit1. Did I make a mistake when creating this Unit?

Comment: According to the question you are using Delphi!! Anyway, I don't know much about Lazarus and FPC. The call to `Application.CreateForm` would normally live in the .dpr file.

Comment: That would explain a lot of my confusion, I had meant to put pascal there!

Comment: The concepts covered in my answer  still apply to FPC/Lazarus although I guess the list view implementation could differ somewhat.

Comment: The [`Application.CreateForm`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/forms/tapplication.createform.html) is in the project's `*.lpr` file and has the same meaning as in Delphi.

Comment: Okay so I tried your first method and I receiving the following error: unit1.pas(50,32) Only class class methods, class properties and class variables can be access in class methods.   This is happening at the MyOtherForm.SetListView(ListView); call

Comment: The error message tells you the answer. You are calling this from a class method. You need to call from an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and best way would be to add a method to the receiving form - that is, the form with the ListView on it -- that says "AddThingsToListView", and have it accept the things you want to add (Probably a TListItem?)

That way, you can then call

```
MyMainForm.AddThingsToListView(ANewListItem);
```

from anywhere.

In other words, don't pass the list view to the non-modal form; instead, have the main form be able to accept additions to its list view.

Comment: That doesn't work. You can't pass `ANewListItem` since you need to have the list view itself in order to create a new item. Specifically you have to call `TListItems.Add` or one of its friends.

Answer (score 0):

What I do: for this kind of situation:
I usually declare a data module, and put most of the code that doesn't fit neatly into non-GUI library units into the Data module.  The data module can refer to the forms and vice versa, but none of the forms refer to each other.

In this example, your Form2 can use the DataModule, and you can do either:

1. Have a global reference to the MainForm's ListView in the datamodule, and use that from your form.
2. Have a function/class in the datamodule that lets you update the list, and call that from your form.

Either way, your form only has to know about the data module, and the data module does the rest. You can add/delete/change forms, and usually you only have to update the DM.