# Lazarus Listview from form1 that can be added to by form2

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I apologize for having another similar question but I was hoping to find a simpler solution to a problem I am having.

I have a listview in form1 that I want form2 to be able to add to. Form2 is created by form1 by a button press. Form2 has a listview and when I click on a button in form2 I want it to add all items to the listview in form1 and close form2. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

*I tried using windows messaging but for some reason Lazarus doesn't work with TWM_CopyData.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Pascal passing a listview from mainform to a nonmodal form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095001/pascal-passing-a-listview-from-mainform-to-a-nonmodal-form).

Answer (score 4):

Since I would prefer the unit referencing, here is what might help you. In the `Form2` is declared public property `TargetListView` into which is assigned the list view from the `Form1` before the `Form2` is shown. Now you have the access to the `Form1` list view from the `Form2` scope and you can copy the items there before you close it.

Here is the simplified code for the first unit:

```
unit Unit1;

uses
  Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end; 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.TargetListView := ListView1;
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

And here is the simplified code for the second unit:

```
unit Unit2;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    TargetListView: TListView;
  end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  TargetListView.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
      TargetListView.Items.Add.Assign(ListView1.Items[I]);
  finally
    TargetListView.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: Now looking on the code posted [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10095057/960757); they are almost the same. Instead of private field `FListView` with `SetListView` setter function I've used only the public property `TargetListView` but the thought is the same. And all of this might be applicable to Delphi as well.

Comment: Forgot to explain what David's note from his post, that you'll have a *dependency on the implementation of the main form*, which applies also for this code, means. It means that if you destroy the list view on the `Form1` (in my case) and then click on the button on the `Form2` you will get the access violation error because the list view into which you try to copy the items doesn't exist anymore. But I think you're not going to do this. If so, leave a comment or update your question.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, don't forget to accept answers if they resolves your questions ([`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541)). If you have any further questions related to your problem, don't hesitate to leave a comment here ;-)